# EF6 adding child records that have two foreign keys to the parent table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

My problem involves a table of tasks, and their relationships.

The business model is that each task has a list of tasks that need to be complete before it can start.

My C# EF6 winforms application has the following 2 tables  ( simplified )

I have a task table with primary key

```
[TaskID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

and a predecessor table  with only two columns

```
[TaskID] [int] NOT NULL,
[PredecessorTaskId] [int] NOT NULL
```

where the primary key made up of both columns.

`TaskID` and `PredecessorTaskId` are both foreign keys for the task table.

In the designer edmx I can't see the predecessor table, instead there is a line running from the Task table back to itself.

The code created by running the custom tool is

```
public partial class task
{
    public task()
    {
        this.NeedsTasks = new HashSet<task>();
        this.NeededByTasks = new HashSet<task>();
    }
  public int TaskID { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<task> NeedsTasks { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<task> NeededByTasks { get; set; }
  // other fields 
}
```

I cant find any code generated for the predecessor table

Now for my code

```
public static void SaveWorkflow(List<task> workflowTasks)
    {
        short offset = 1;
        using (var db = new MyDbContext)
        {
            task task = null;
            task prevtask = null;

            foreach (var workflowTask in workflowTasks)
            {
                workflowTask.TaskOffsetID = offset;
                offset++;
                task = db.tasks.Add(workflowTask);
                //db.SaveChanges();
                if (prevtask != null)
                {
                    task.NeedsTasks.Add(prevtask);
                }
                prevtask = task;

            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

If I run the above code and query the records using

```
select k.taskid, p.taskid, p.predecessortaskId 
from task k left outer join predecessor p on k.taskid = p.taskid
where  etc
```

I get

```
taskid  taskid  predecessortaskid
568187  568187  568188
568188  NULL    NULL
568189  568189  568187
568190  568190  568189
568191  568191  568190
```

This is not what I want, as it is the first predecessor that should have the null data, indicating that the first task does not need any other task to start.

If I uncomment the call to SaveChanges inside the loop, I get the correct results

However I would much prefer to have only one call to SaveChanges, so there is a transaction.

I also tried adding

```
prevtask.NeededByTasks.Add(task);
```

after the call to

```
task.NeedsTasks.Add(prevtask);
```

however it made no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **is** actually the first predecessor (i.e. the *first* element in your `workflowTasks` list) that has the `NULL` data in your SQL result. You can see it if you extend your SQL query slightly:

```
select k.taskid, p.taskid, p.predecessortaskId, k.taskoffsetid
from task k left outer join predecessor p on k.taskid = p.taskid
where  etc
order by taskoffsetid
```

The result is now:

```
taskid  taskid  predecessortaskid  taskoffsetid
568188  NULL    NULL               1
568187  568187  568188             2
568189  568189  568187             3
568190  568190  568189             4
568191  568191  568190             5
```

However, the `taskid` hasn't been generated in the same order as you've set the `taskoffsetid` and as the tasks are sorted in your input list.

If you insert a complex object graph with many entities you can't assume any certain order in which the keys are generated. The sequence of INSERT statements EF sends to the database is under EF control. I would not rely by any means on an expectation that the keys are generated in a specific order which I would like, unless I force the key generation explicitly by multiple calls of `SaveChanges` (as you already have seen).

You can solve the problem to run multiple `SaveChanges` calls in a single transaction by wrapping the whole loop into a `using (var scope = new TransactionScope()) { ... scope.Complete(); }` block.

However, the question is: Do you really need a sorted `taskid`? Without refering to the key at all you could actually run through the tasks in the order of their dependencies, for example like so:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext)
{
    var task = db.Tasks.Where(t => !t.NeedsTasks.Any()).SingleOrDefault();
    while (task != null)
    {
        // run task / do something with task...
        task = task.NeededByTasks.SingleOrDefault(); // lazy loading
    }
}
```